# Threading in python is not running concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-multithreading

```
from time import sleep
import threading


def sleep_and_print(duration, name):
    sleep(duration)
    print(name)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=sleep_and_print(2, "three second sleep"))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=sleep_and_print(1, "one second sleep"))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

https://www.online-python.com/DcL2tujayw

For the above code, my expectation is that the threads will be started async, and "one second sleep" will be printed before "three second sleep".  However that is not the order this happens, they appear to be running synchronously.

From the docs I've read I believe this should work, but I am new to python.  I tried using ThreadPoolExecute but could not make that work either.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not executing the function in the threads, you are doing it in the `threading.Thread` declaration. `target` should be the function name and the parameters should be sent as `args`

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=sleep_and_print, args=(3, "three second sleep"))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=sleep_and_print, args=(1, "one second sleep"))
```

Test

```
for _ in range(10):
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=sleep_and_print, args=(1, 'thread 1'))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=sleep_and_print, args=(1, 'thread 2'))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Output

```
thread 1
thread 2
thread 1
thread 2
thread 2
thread 1
thread 2
thread 1
thread 1
thread 2
thread 2
thread 1
thread 2
thread 1
thread 2
thread 1
thread 1
thread 2
thread 1
thread 2
```

Comment: @guy that is perfect thank you!

Comment: All good but for one nit-pick: There is no "`threading.Thread` _declaration_" in OP's example code. `t1=...` is an assignment, `threading.Thread(...)` is a function call, `target=...` is a keyword argument expression, and `sleep_and_print(...)` is another function call. There are precious few actual declarations in the Python language. One example would be `global foo`, but I can't think of any others just at this moment. Functions and classes, for example, would be _declared_ in other languages, but in Python, `def...` and `class...` are executable statements.